# How to insert geometry into postegreSQL table in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, postgis

I want to insert geometry data into a table in postgreSQL.
I get the same error after everything I tried.
The error I get is : `ERROR [42601] : syntax error on or near "6670931.45"; Error while executing the query`

Here's my code :

```vb
Dim test As String = "91844271.14 6670931.45"
        Call executeCommand("insert into netgeo_cable(geom) values (st_geometryfromtext(MULTILINESTRING((" & test & ")),2154)", myConnection)
```

`executeCommand()` is a simple method to send a request :

```vb
Sub executeCommand(ByVal sql As String, ByRef myConnection As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection, Optional ByRef adBaseAccess As String = "")
        Dim myCommand As OdbcCommand
        Try
            myCommand = New OdbcCommand(sql, myConnection)
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Requête échouée" & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I checked that I have the right constraint as `MULTILINESTRING` in my table. The SRID is the same that the one declared in the table.

I don't see where is my syntax error.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: You should use parameters. If you show `executeCommand()` there is most likely relevant information in there.

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi I've edited my post with `executeCommand()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`st_geometryfromtext` expects a string, so its content must be quoted

```
 Call executeCommand("insert into netgeo_cable(geom) values (st_geometryfromtext('MULTILINESTRING((" & test & "))',2154))", myConnection)
```

Comment: I corrected as you suggested. It solves the problem however I've another one error : `syntax error at the end of the input. Error while executing the query.`

Comment: @LyessD the original query was missing a closing parenthesis